# How to check a checkbox while doing protractor e2e using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, protractor

I'm currently doing a testcase for a program, and I need to check the checkbox in the e2e test.

Being new to e2e, I don't have a successful idea on how to do it for checkboxes

Any help or links appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your checkbox using locators, read up on them [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md)

```
//in case your checkbox has an ID
var foo = element(by.id('checkboxId'));
foo.click();

//in case your checkbox doesn't have an ID or a unique identifier, use CSS
var bar = $('[type="checkbox"]');
bar.click();
```

Comment: additionally you can verify if the chechbox is checked with `foo.isSelected()` (this returns a promise)

Comment: if you don't have jquery, then you can use  `element(by.css())` or `element(by.xpath())`  You can get css/xpaths by right-clicking on an inspected element in Chrome debugger